# Cannot save files in Sublime Text 2

Tags: permissions, sublime-text

As stated in the title, I am unable to save my sublime text 2 files. I tried running the `gksudo subl` command and "Save as" but to no avail. Any other workaround for this? What is causing this issue?

Console shows:

```
'error: Unable to save ~/Documents/flaskcode/helloflask.py
    Writing file /home/justinian/Documents/flaskcode/hello.py with encoding UTF-8'
```

Comment: Can you open the "Console" within Sublime Text and give us any relevant output?  FYI Sublime Text 3 is available with many improvements, including being installable from a `.deb` file, vs manual setup/installation.

Comment: *Updated with the output from my console. At one point gksudo subl solved this issue but now the error persists.

Comment: I just installed sublime 3 and everything works.